# Module custom template

Tags: magento

I am looking for a way to customize a template.
I would like to do it directly in my module to have this change only if the module is activated. 
The template I need to change is  in checkout.xml.

I made some research and I find out that I have to play with  in the config.xml and then have another xml file to have my customs. But I still a bit confused about the structure. 
For me the best would be to have something like:

- app/code/local/company/module/etc/config.xml
- app/code/local/company/module/etc/login_layout.xml
- app/code/local/company/module/design/login.phtml  (this would be my new template)

Is it possible? How?

I hope you can help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible but it is not a wise thing to do as you are differing your extension to be different than common Magento experience so expect lot of support requests and oddities from users that will use your stuff later.

you can write a observer that adds your layout descriptions before controller dispatch on the fly , set the layouts to be included from any path on runtime $blockObject->setTemplate() method. Guaranteed that no-one will understand your goals and will call you a fool for obscuring things that are essential for Magento development. Apart that overriding your templates in custom themes will become somewhat harder.

so I suggest: put layout files to theme/layout/ folder and templates to theme/templates

Comment: This module is a private module. The goal is to use our authentication system. I want to do it this way to be able to deactivate the module...
What is the absolute path for  theme/layout/?

Comment: if you deactivate the module from app/local/etc then templates are never used anyway. theme = your used theme

Comment: And what would be the path of theme? app/code/local/company/module/theme ?

Comment: dude do you have any idea how Magento themes work?  app/design/frontend/your/theme/templates

Comment: I ask you this question because I would like to have the template inside the folder of my module... But now I understand that's not easily possible.

Comment: it is easily possible :) but it is deprecated usage of Magento and bad practice